# "Invalid lambda function" when trying to configure SES email receiving rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I created simple Lambda function for processing Amazon SES incoming email.

Function works, testing it with SES data works from Lambda editing panel.

When trying to create SES email receiving rule always getting identical errors:

```
Invalid Lambda function:
arn:aws:lambda:region:userid:function:functionname
(Request ID: requestid)
```

Tried to add roles for this lambda via command line:

```
aws lambda add-permission
--function-name arn:aws:lambda:region:userid:function:functionname
--statement-id=GiveSESPermissionToInvokeFunction
--principal=ses.amazonaws.com
--action=lambda:InvokeFunction
--source-account=userid
--region "region"
```

role is added successfully, but it's not helping.

Comment: SES Verified and out of sandbox ?

Comment: Why do you have `--statement-id=GiveSESPermissionToInvokeFunction`. It should be `--statement-id GiveSESPermissionToInvokeFunction` etc. etc.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Having the same issue this side, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 9):

The Lambda function needs to be in the same AWS region as you are configuring the SES rule in.